# GRID Radar chart Custom Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Hi want to enlarge the distance of my grid.
I used a Radar chart of the amcharts library
I cant find a properties that allow me to do that.

HTML

```
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/kelly.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#chartdiv{
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
}
```

JS

```
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 266
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 336
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 290
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 325
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 40
}];


/* Create axes */
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";



var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

/* Create and configure series */
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "litres";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
```

I want to enlarge(distance of the label) of the grid with a custom value
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

JS
check this https://codepen.io/itsvinitjain/pen/gOmWJWe

```
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 266
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 336
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 290
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 325
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 40
}];


/* Create axes */
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";



var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

/* Create and configure series */
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "litres";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 100;
```